Symbology changes when clipping raster QGIS
I'm using land cover/land use .tif imagery available at the Esri living atlas (https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/landcoverexplorer/#mapCenter=-73.64341%2C10.81044%2C11&mode=step&timeExtent=2017%2C2021&year=2022&renderingRule=0). I wanted to clip the images for areas of 4km radius in QGIS and then use the clipped images in an R script in order to calculate some landscape metrics.
When I open the downloaded .tif in QGIS it is displayed with the following symbology. Note that I'm interested in the covers 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 and 11 that are shown.

However, when I clip and save the raster for only the 4km radius area I'm interested in the symbology changes.

What can I do to maintain the symbology for the clipped raster? (other than copy and paste the style from the original rasteR) I'm worried that the clipped images won't work for calculating the lanscape metrics.
The data types of the input and output rasters are the same

The palette is telling with which color each pixel value should be painted. I think that for calculating metrics the colors do not matter. Verify with the query tool that the pixels values in the original paletted image and in the clipped image are the same. If they are then just go analyzing.

@BERA can you plese clarify what do you mean by data types?

@BERA the data types are indeed the same

The symbology wont have any effect on the calculations
